# `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found, run system call from MATLAB that links to glibc different than what's in matlab bin path

Tags: matlab, linker, dynamic-linking, glibc

I'm trying to circumvent using MEX to link to MATLAB and just call a binary using "!" as in:

```
>> !template_image_rigid -args ....
template_image_rigid: /opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version    `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.40.0)
template_image_rigid: /opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libdirac_encoder.so.0)
```

Is there a way to easily fix this dynamic link issue from within MATLAB? I know I can recompile the source with MATLAB and use a MEX call, but since it takes a while to run the solver I just want to run it as shell command and import text data later into MATLAB.

If it helps, the source & CMakeLists.txt can be found here: https://github.com/pkarasev3/nlmagick/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler:

```
 setenv('foo',num2str(some_value) )
 !LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""   &&   ./my_binary -f $foo
 disp('done with external program!')
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother on an old question. Can you please help me understand what is the `setenv('foo',num2str(some_value) )` doing? thks in advance ;)

Comment: it sets an environment variable in the shell, so it can be used in the subsequent shell command that starts with "!" ... note that this example is linux/unix, for windows youd need syntax changes like % instead of $

Answer (score 2):

Grr, community = fail.

Diagnoising: do !gnome-terminal from within matlab and look at "env":

```
env | grep Matlab
```

which gives

```
XKEYSYMDB=/opt/MatlabR2010a/X11/app-defaults/XKeysymDB
MATLABPATH=/opt/MatlabR2010a/toolbox/local
XAPPLRESDIR=/opt/MatlabR2010a/X11/app-defaults
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/os/glnxa64:/opt/MatlabR2010a/bin/glnxa64:/opt/MatlabR2010a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/opt/MatlabR2010a/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/a  md64/server:/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
OSG_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/openscenegraph/lib/glnxa64
TOOLBOX=/opt/MatlabR2010a/toolbox
XFILESEARCHPATH=/opt/MatlabR2010a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/locale/%L/%T/%N%S::/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
MATLAB=/opt/MatlabR2010a
```

Ok so the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad.

Trick: write a poltergeist script and run it from gnome-terminal, Launch it from Matlab with:

```
!./hack.sh  RunStuffThatLinksElsewhere
```

where hack.sh is a script with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
gnome-terminal --command="${1}"
```

so an easy test is to try it with "eog", this hack gets around the link issue and lets you run it from within matlab...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by replacing the version of libstdc++.so.6 with a newer version from my system (I use ubuntu 12.04).

First find the system version of libstdc++.so.6.

From the command line type:

```
locate libstdc++.so.6
```

My system version of libstdc was

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Then replace the matlab libstdc version with a link to the system libstdc.

From the command line type (replace [....] with you settings):

```
cd [matlab_dir]/sys/os/glnx86 
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6-OLD 
ln -s [your_system_version_of_libstdc] libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: For some versions of Matlab, this can cause the Matlab executable to fail to run.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem. My solution also uses a poltergeist script like other answers. The script is as follows (poltergeist.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
eval "$@"
```

It basically resets the library path and subsequently evaluates the call given by the arguments to the script. From within matlab I then call in this manner:

```
system([pwd,'/poltergeist.sh echo hello world!']);
```

The advantage to this approach is that you can dynamically modify the call command within matlab. As far as I know this is not possible using the *bang* syntax in the currently provided answers.